# SignalR - can't invoke hub method from client connected to multiple hubs

Tags: angular, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I setup 2 SignalR connections on the client - one per each hub. Connections are established the following way:

```
var firstConnection = Signalr.connect();
var secondConnection = Signalr.connect({ hubName: 'MySecondHub' });
```

Calling hub methods on the default connection works, but when I do...

```
this.secondConnection.invoke('My2ndHubMethod').then(data => {
     . . . 
});
```

... it just logs the following in the console
`SignalRConnection. Start invoking 'My2ndHubMethod'...`

Seems like the call never actually returns.

When I change `SignalRConfiguration.transport` from `ConnectionTransports.webSocket` to `ConnectionTransports.longPolling` it produces following error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
```

And logs following to the console `Invoking 'My2ndHubMethod' failed. Rejecting promise...`

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the error was caused by Hub1 and Hub2 having different number of arguments in their constructors. Once I put same number and type of arguments for both it started working.